# Performance Gains: SQLite and MYSQL Functions

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I am currently converting a PHP web app with a MYSQL database to a SQLite one. On the MYSQL side I have a function which I call in one of my queries. SQLite does not allow for stored functions so I am creating that function and binding it in PHP.

What is the difference in performance between the two methods? Is the necessity of binding a PHP function and calling it for each row in SQLite still faster than using the MYSQL function?

MYSQL Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SortLab` (location VARCHAR(16))
RETURNS int
NO SQL
BEGIN
 DECLARE working VARCHAR(16);
 DECLARE leftStr VARCHAR(16);
 DECLARE rightStr VARCHAR(16);
 DECLARE outcome INT;

 SET working = REGEXP_REPLACE(location, '[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]*', '_');
 SET leftStr = LEFT(working, INSTR(working, '_')-1);
 SET rightStr = LPAD(RIGHT(working, LENGTH(working)-INSTR(working, '_')), 4, 0);

 SET outcome = CONCAT(leftStr, rightStr);
 RETURN outcome;
END$$
```

Psuedo PHP for SQLite

```
function sorter($value) {
 result = replace(value, regex, '_');
 result = left(result);
 result = right(result);
}

$db->createFunction('sortLab', 'sorter')

$results = $db->query(SELECT sortLab(data) FROM table);
```

I realise that in this example I can use the existing functions in SQLite but I have pulled this and written the psuedo from a much larger query

Comment: You better test by yourself rather than get a answer here. Usually it's slower if you need to run a PHP command for every row in database. My bets are that you will have a bad performance. But how bad will depends on how many users, how many rows, how complex the function, among other things.